# NestJs- Error: Cannot find module (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I updated my NodeJs to the latest version 10.16.3, then I installed NestJs Client using

> npm install -g @nestjs/cli

and then created a new project using

> nest new nest-demo

but when I tried to run it

> npm run start:dev

application threw an error "internal/modules/cjs/loader.js"

[image]

Comment: Did you forget to run npm install ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot one step.

```
1. npm install -g @nestjs/cli
2. nest new nest-demo
3. cd nest-demo
4. npm i
5. npm run start:dev
```